# Make non-http request with node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for a way to query a non-http url, i.e. a want to make a request in my node.js not using the HTTP-protocol (nor HTTPS). Node.js does offer the HTTP package which helps to build and execute a http-call. Does something similar exists for using an abitrary protocol?

Comment: Are you talking about opening sockets?

Comment: I'm not bound to use sockets, I simply want to request a non http-url. Can I achieve this with using sockets?

Comment: What is this "non-HTTP URL"? Please take a look at the [common URI schemes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes) to further specify which one you are planning to use.

Comment: I'm working on a plugin for Adobes Lightroom and the SDK offers the possibility to access the pluging from exterieur with an URL. The URL looks like lightroom://com.name.of.plugin/parameters.

Comment: @imikbox Adobe protocols are notoriously difficult to implement; I should know - I implemented RTMP in Perl to monitor live streams for activity. Not something I'd rush to repeat. Have you looked to see if any open-source projects have implemented libraries for the protocol you seek?

Comment: Thanks so far for the answers. I actually don't want to implement the whole protocol. I don't need to set-up a communication via the lightroom-protocol, I only need to make a simple request to the specific URL. It's kind of similar to when to click on the Apple App Store Link on a Website which brings up iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

The protocol is important. Actually the protocol is *vital*. URLs specify where to go, *and* specify how. There's a world of difference between ftp:// and http:// and https:// and magnet:// and a variety of others. You can achieve ALL of it using sockets. But sounds like you want a high-level packet to make your connection easy - and that just isn't generically possible for all protocols.

Comment: Well, if there doesn't exist a generic solution a must use sockets. However, I've not yet figured out how to use sockets with a certain URL. How for example would this work with net.createConnection() ?

Comment: @imikbox you need to **thoroughly** read the protocol definition for your "lightroom" product. Things you need to know include: what is the port to connect to if the port isn't defined? Should you use TCP or UDP? That's just to make a *connection*. We haven't even started with how you should frame or encode messages at layer 4 and above of the OSI stack. You may be way out of your depth here.